# How can I control the number of processes started with scikit-learn's joblib?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, hpc, joblib

**Background**
When carrying out an embarrassingly parallel task on large datasets with scikit-learn, it is convenient to do so on a cluster in a high-performance computing (HPC) environment. Scikit-learn provides support for parallelization by allowing the user to specify the number of cores to use in parallel via the *n_jobs* argument. This should in principle make it straightforward to match the number of cores used within the analysis pipeline to the number of processors requested from the scheduler in the HPC environment.

**Problem**
IT have pointed out to me that the number of processes running per single job (namely 7) exceeded the number of processors I had requested (namely 2) although I had in fact set scikit-learn's *n_job* argument to 2. As I have been told, the result is that these processes are now blocking each other from using the limited computing resources (a bit like musical chairs, I'm imagining) thereby creating unnecessary overhead and making inefficient use of the cluster. The number of threads were detected by running `pstree PID`.

**Question**
Where do the additional 5 processes come from? How can I control the number of processes in scikit-learn to match the number of processors actually allocated to the cluster job?

**Code example**
I have created a small example to illustrate this behavior (Python 3.6.8, numpy 1.18.1, scikit-learn 0.20.3)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
import os
import time
from sklearn.model_selection import permutation_test_score
from sklearn import datasets, svm

n_folds = 3
n_perm = 12000
n_jobs = 2  # The number of tasks to run in parallel
n_cpus = 2  # Number of CPUs assigned to this process

pid = os.getpid()
print("PID: %i" % pid)

print("loading iris dataset")
X, y = datasets.load_iris(return_X_y=True)

# Control which CPUs are made available for this script
cpu_arg = ''.join([str(ci) + ',' for ci in list(range(n_cpus))])[:-1]
cmd = 'taskset -cp %s %i' % (cpu_arg, pid)
print("executing command '%s' ..." % cmd)
os.system(cmd)

t1 = time.time()
res = permutation_test_score(svm.SVC(kernel='linear'), X, y, cv=n_folds,
                             n_permutations=n_perm, n_jobs=n_jobs,
                             verbose=3)
t_delta = time.time() - t1
ips = n_perm / t_delta
print("number of iterations per second: %.02f it/s" % ips)
```

When checking with `htop`, it appears that exactly the number of CPUs are running at 100 % that I have indeed requested via `n_jobs=2` and `n_cpus=2` - two in this case. When I look at the threads using `pstree PID`, however, I can see 6 processes running instead of the expected two processes.

Requesting only `n_jobs=1` and `n_cpus=1` results in `htop` showing one CPU being 100 % busy and `pstree PID` likewise shows only a single processing running, as expected.

**Additional information and further attempts**

Some information on my OS as per `uname -a`:

`Linux COMPUTERNAME 4.15.0-96-generic #97-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 1 03:25:46 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

... and about the CPUs as per `lscpu | grep -e CPU -e core`:

```
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
CPU(s):              8
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-7
Thread(s) per core:  2
CPU family:          6
Model name:          Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2123 CPU @ 3.60GHz
CPU MHz:             1200.050
CPU max MHz:         3900,0000
CPU min MHz:         1200,0000
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-7
```

My example code now allows control of the number of CPUs that are made available for code execution using the `taskset` command. So I can separately manipulate the number of tasks requested to run in parallel in scikit-learn (`n_jobs`) and the number of available CPUs (`n_cpus`). This allowed me to compare four scenarios to each other:

1. `n_jobs=1` and `n_cpus=1`: 360.24 it/s, `htop` shows one CPU busy, `pstree PID` shows one thread running.
2. `n_jobs=2` and `n_cpus=2`: 658.40 it/s, `htop` shows two CPUs busy, `pstree PID` shows 6 threads running.
3. `n_jobs=2` and `n_cpus=1`: 336.80 it/s, `htop` shows one CPU busy, `pstree PID` shows 6 threads running.
4. `n_jobs=1` and `n_cpus=2`: 358.60 it/s, `htop` shows one CPU busy, `pstree PID` shows one thread running.

It seems that `pstree` always depends on the number of threads requested in the scikit-learn API. The number of CPUs shown by `htop` to be active is the number of CPUs that are available to the script **and** that are also in use. So only scenario 2 results in two CPUs being busy. Likewise, processing speed (measured in iterations per second) is only increased in the parallel case if CPUs are available **and** used (also scenario 2). Crucially, the number of threads, which is six according to `pstree` and hence larger than the number of CPUs, did not indicate that they interfered with each other for limited CPUs. Only scenario 3 showed that processing appeared slower when two jobs were requested but only one CPU was made available. This was slower than scenario 1.

I am starting to wonder if `pstree` really is a good diagnostic for the efficiency of parallel processing and how it is different from `htop`.

Comment: how many cores per cpu? it may be 7 processes are spawned in a quad-core 2 cpu architecture leaving 1 (out of 8 cores) to the kernel / daemon processes. I'd advise looking into ulimit (linux distros) to limit number of cores on a per application basis

Comment: According to `lscpu` I have

CPU(s):              8
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-7
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  4
Socket(s):           1

And based on `ulimit -a` the max user processes is 255791 (what unit is this? - can't be CPUs or cores). So I ran the above code example within a bash script that set this to sth small like `ulimit -u 8`. Since this is probably the wrong unit, that gave me the message "fork: Resource temporarily unavailable"

Comment: Hi, please provide minimal replicable example of your command and OS environment. Also have you changed n_jobs to 1 cpu? I would execute python script with `ulimit -u 2` & `n_jobs` set to 1 to access 1 cpu with 2 cores (or 2 processes)

Comment: I have updated the original question provide information about the OS and added the bash wrapper that I used to test your ulimit idea. Setting `ulimit -u 2` and requesting only `n_jobs=1` resulted in the same behavior and message output "... Resource temporarily unavailable" as in the `n_jobs=2` scenario described above.

Comment: You have probably run out of RAM and paging memory, either handle paging in the application (by saving data to a disk) and reduce memory overhead or add more RAM to your environment

Comment: You shouldn't blindly do what people tell you to do. `ulimit -u 2` sets to two the limit for the **total number of processes for your user**. One of those is probably the `sshd` process under your username and one is the shell, therefore you simply can't start new processes.

Comment: @HristoIliev, that is sensible advice in general. Yes, I believe that `ulimit -u` changes something else than what was supposed to be controlled here (for its previous value of 255791 clearly is not the number of CPUs on my machine - see above). So your comment about what that number actually means makes more sense to me. I just wanted to document whatever there is that people have kindly suggested so far.

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into this problem, and after spending a week on it I could resolve it. You have to restrict scikit-learn models' access to resources. Here is the example snippet:

```
from joblib import parallel_backend

with parallel_backend("threading", n_jobs=1):
    model.fit(X,y)
```

You may also need to set the n_jobs of the scikit-learn model:

```
import sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier as KNN

model = KNN(n_jobs=1)
```